# project help on image processing

Tags: image-processing

how to start a project on image processing? what are the initial steps?
what to read or which language/library to use?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend starting with a language that you are familiar with. I happen to be a python guy, and you can install the [Python Imaging Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) site package and use that to create whatever filters you would like. Matlab is popular in university classes as it does matrix math very quickly and images can easily be represented as matrices.

Now that we have a language and a toolkit decided, you can work on implementing algorithmic filters. I would recommend doing a little searching on the following, which have relatively straight forward implementations if you're willing to learn the math:

1. Noise reduction ( also known as the Gaussian )
2. Histogram analysis ( used for contrast alterations )
3. Edge detection ( equivalent to sharpening )

Answer (score 0):

See if [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) does what you need.